# Segmentation error, C File handling program

Tags: c, file-handling

**Easy access program**

Using linux first of all. I am trying to make a program that will first sign up a user in case he ain't got an account after that he will be directed to a login screen where he will enter his account details and then will be logged in. After that he will be given options to provide easy access to websites e.t.c. Like if the user enters 1 he will be directed to f.b, 2 for quora and so on. I successfully managed to code the program to the log in phase but i did it in a single function i.e main(), so i thought it would be nice if i had separate functions for performing specific tasks. I have coded it this time in separate functions, but i am getting segmentation error this time when i try to open FILE using fopen(). And also please tell me some way to open a website in a browser using console command. Like we have in windows (start www.facebook.com e.g). Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct user_data {
    char name[50];
    unsigned long password;
};

struct user_data new_user;                  // Will hold the data of new
struct user_data data_ver;                  // Will hold the data read

void sign_up(void);
void sign_in(void);

int main(void) {
    beginning:                                      // Beginning label in case of invalid input
    printf("\t\t\t\t WELCOME TO EASY ACCESS APPLICATION");
    printf("\n\n\nIf you have an account press 1.\n\nPress 2 for sign up.");
    char user_choice;                               // Wil hold the
    // user_choice i.e whether he wants to sign up / sign in
    user_choice = getchar();
    if (user_choice == '1') {
        sign_in();                                 // In case of 1 goto sign in page
    }
    else if (user_choice == '2') {
        sign_up();             // Opening file);
        // In case of 2 goto sign up page
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n\n");
        puts("Press any key to continue...");
        getchar();
        system("clear");
        goto beginning;
    }
    return 0;
}

void sign_up(void) {
    FILE *data = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file.");
        scanf("%c");
        system("clear");
    }
    system("clear");
    printf("\t\t----------------------------\n"
           "\t\t|                          |\n"
           "\t\t|     SIGN UP PAGE         |\n"
           "\t\t|                          |\n"
           "\t\t----------------------------");

    printf("\n\nName:");
    scanf("%c");                // Dummy scanf
    gets(new_user.name);            // Getting name into the struct
    printf("\nPassword.");
    scanf("%lu", &new_user.password);    // Getting pass into the struct
    fprintf(data, "%s %lu\n", new_user.name, new_user.password);       //Feeding data into FILE
    system("clear");
    printf("\n\nSign up complete. :)  ");
    printf("\n\nYou will now be directed to the sign in page. ");
    printf("\nPress any key to contine...");
    scanf("%c");
    system("clear");
    fclose(data);
}

void sign_in(void) {

}
```

I am getting the error on the first line of sign_up function where i am opening FILE.

[image]

Comment: This `scanf("%c");` is not what you think. Where do you want scanf to store the read char?

Comment: @SeekAddo Well, its a dummy scanf(). I am using it as a gethc() function.

Comment: @SeekAdoo And by the way it won't store the readed char anywhere (if i am not wrong) since i have not specified its location

Comment: @SeekAddo Well it gave me a few warnings for that. If i replace it to *c will it make my program right?

Comment: @SeekAddo Thanks, i am not getting an error now after replacing %c with *c. But i do not understand why i got the error. Elaboration on that please?

Comment: Post the error messages you are getting in your question

Comment: printf("\t\t----------------------------\n"
           "\t\t|                          |\n"
           "\t\t|     SIGN UP PAGE         |\n"
           "\t\t|                          |\n"
           "\t\t----------------------------");
This was displayed and after it it was stated "Segmentation error"

Comment: Please paste all errors in your question not as comment

Comment: @SeekAddo i've posted the error pic.

Comment: I edited your code. change `scanf("%c")` to `scanf("%*c"); and run the code. I am not getting any segFault from your code, just have to work on your logic after sign up.

Comment: @Muneeb _**"Well, its a dummy scanf()"**_start from the good book first.

Comment: @PeterJ I am learning from a good book (Practical C programming, steve oualline), i learned to use this from a youtube video. Because if you place a getchar() before a statement in which you are reading data into a string, that data won't be read because \n is encountered by gets() which terminates it. Perhaps it would be nice if you suggest me some good books for C

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c")` expects a pointer where the read character will be stored. scanf() doesn't know if you provided the pointer, it just read the destination address from the expected stack location. Effectively scanf() takes a random address and writes the character there.

Use `getchar();` or `char Dummy; scanf("%c",&Dummy);`.

Comment: `%*c` is also a thing.

Comment: @melpomene There is another thing i wanted to ask. The fgets keeps skipping input because i press enter. Any way to solve it?

Comment: @Muneeb Never use `scanf` for user input. Use `fgets` only.

Comment: @melpomene Does strcmp() also count the \n character in a string?

Comment: @melpomene And one more thing, is there a command in linux terminal which directly opens website/webpage in browser. Like we have start command in windows cmd prompt.